# Slow SQL query on Sybase

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization, sap-ase

I'm trying to extract information from a database. Sybase ASE 16 (not sure of the SP thouogh). I don't have direct access to the database myself so I have to ask a collegue to run the code to extract the information that I then use.

First, the following code is executed:

```
create table AAA (
    Operacion varchar(10) null,
    Actual smallint null,
    Castigado smallint null,
    RentasVar smallint null)
go
```

Table Indice is populated from a text file using a bcp. Actual, Castigado and RentasVar are either 0 or 1.

Then this code:

```
create view XXX as
    select Operacion, cast(convert(char(8), FecAplica, 112) as int) as FecAplica,
            IdPolizaSeg, SaldoInsSeg, CapitalSeg, InteresSeg,
            IvaSeg, MontoSeg, SegVenc
        from SEG_Vencim
        where Operacion in (
            select Operacion from AAA 
                where Actual=1)
go

create view YYY as
    select Operacion, IdTipoMov, DescMov, IdMoneda, StatuMov,
            cast(convert(char(8), FecMov, 112) as int) as FecMov,
            cast(convert(char(8), FecVencMov, 112) as int) as FecVencMov,
            cast(convert(char(8), FecPago, 112) as int) as FecPago,
            MontoMov, IvaMov, TotalMov, MontoDelPago
        from Movimientos
        where (Operacion in (
            select Operacion from AAA where Castigado=1))
                or (Operacion in (
                    select Operacion from AAA where Actual=1)
                        and (FecPago=null or FecPago>dateadd(dd, -30, current_date())))
go
```

Field Operacion in Movimientos is varchar(10). I cannot modify this table.

A bcp instruction is issued to copy XXX's content into a text file. The task is completed a couple seconds after, having written a file of aprox. 140 MB.
A bcp instruction is issued to copy YYY's content into a text file. The task is completed after almost 7 hours, having written a file of aprox. 70 MB.

So my problem is that the second bcp instruction takes too long.
I read that functions on where clause can be inefficient so I asked my colleague to try again using

```
and (FecPago=null or FecPago>='2020-09-30'))
```

instead of

```
and (FecPago=null or FecPago>dateadd(dd, -30, current_date())))
```

but it didn't help.

AAA has between 80,000 and 90,000 records. Would putting an index on it help?
I read that unnesting queries might [help](http://dcx.sybase.com/1201/en/dbusage/efficient-sql-queries.html), could that help in my case? if so, why does the nested query in the first query work?

I cannot run tests on my own and don't have access to the execution plans. I realize it probably won't be possible to give me advice on this without me providing additional information.

Comment: This is probably going to be a bit more than can be supported on SO, eg, we would want to see the query plan (ie, `set statement_cache off / set showplan on / set noexec on / go / select * from YYY / go` - this should generate a query plan without executing the query), output from `sp_help/sp_spaceused,1` for all tables in question, and depending on the complexity of the query plan, possibly the `optdiag` output for all tables in question; the easiest/quickest resolution may come from breaking the YYY into 3 separate queries (one for each `OR* clause) to see if there are any issues ...

Comment: if you can get the 3x separate queries running 'fast' then you could try creating YYY as a 3-way UNION (not UNION ALL) of the 3x separate queries; while 'unnesting' the queries may help, ASE 16's optimizer should be smart enough to flatten (ie, 'unnest') the query for you; I'd also suggest adding an index (and updating the index stats) on the `FecPago` column if one doesn't already exist (at a minimum the stats associated with the index may help the optimizer)

Comment: I decided not to use UNION, as I'd rather just put the info. into three separate views/files if have to write the "select..." part three times. So this solution is pretty much equivalent to using UNION instead of OR and I can't believe it worked! My intuition still tells me that my original query should be marginally more efficient, but I'm aware intuition can be treacherous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Sybase but in MSSQL (which shares it's ancestry with Sybase) `OR`s tend to be performance killers. Changing those to `UNION` constructions as markp-fuso suggests often is a good idea.

That said, I wonder what moving the `OR` entirely into the sub-select would do:

```
create view YYY as
    select <your fields>
     from Movimientos
     where Operacion in (select Operacion 
                           from AAA 
                          where ( Castigado = 1)
                             or ( (Actual = 1 and (FecPago=null or FecPago > dateadd(dd, -30, current_date()))))
                        )
```

Not sure what the optimizer might do to the above. Therefore I wonder what happens if we force the operations on AAA to 'materialize' first... Could you give below a try?

```
create view YYY as
    select <your fields>
     from Movimientos m
     JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Operacion 
             from AAA 
            where ( Castigado = 1)
               or ( (Actual = 1 and (FecPago=null or FecPago > dateadd(dd, -30, current_date()))))
          ) d
      ON d.Operacion = m.Operacion
```

Good luck.

PS: apart from using `UNION` to get rid of the `OR`s you can also try to use `WHERE EXISTS()` instead of the `IN()` construction.

Comment: I decided not to use UNION, as I'd rather just put the info. into three separate views/files if have to write the "select..." part three times.

So this solution is pretty much equivalent to using UNION instead of OR and I can't believe it worked! My intuition still tells me that my original query should be marginally more efficient, but I'm aware intuition can be treacherous. Thanks!

Comment: @JavierRivera Glad it works, what version did you end up using? The `WHERE IN()` or the `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT etc` one? The 'weird' thing about SQL is that you pretty much tell the system *what* you want but don't have much grip on *how* you want it; the back-end will interpret your query and figure out the most efficient way to get that data based on lots of factors. Usually this works great, sometimes you have to nudge things a bit by rewording your request.